# Cross reference .xlsx file to main.tex

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, ref

I have `.xlsx` file and I need to reference it in `main.tex` with `\ref{}`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to need to explain yourself much more thoroughly.  What about the txt file do you need to reference?  Its name?  A piece of its content?  Why are you needing to use `\ref`?  What should the output be?

Comment: It's a file.xslx contains information (long table of ~ 1000 rows) and I want to refer to it in the main.tex such as "as shown in supplementary file [1]". @Teepeemm

Comment: as you tagged, using hyperref and `\href{file}{text}`

Comment: I didn't get it, could you please explain more @Fran

Comment: `\usepackage{hyperref}`  in the preamble and then some like `\href{foo.txt}{my foo}` do the job. That is all. To know more, please run `texdoc hyperref`.

Comment: (On the next edit, someone should change the title to also be .xlsx instead of .txt.)  It sounds like you're wanting "as shown in supplementary file [1]", where [1] is a hyperlink that will open the file in question.  Is that correct?  Fran's suggestion should work.  Let us know if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @Fran , that's works well with me.